# Get force of a specific portion of the screen on iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

Is it possible to get the force applied to a part of the screen on iOS 9 on the iPhone 6s?

It's possible to access the `force` attribute of a `UITouch` instance. Is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Look in `UITouch`

```
// Force of the touch, where 1.0 represents the force of an average touch
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public var force: CGFloat { get }
// Maximum possible force with this input mechanism
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public var maximumPossibleForce: CGFloat { get }
```

Comment: I want to get the force of the screen, not a touch.

Comment: What is the force of the screen? `force` will return you value from 0 to 6.66 (for example), measuring the "force" of the `UITouch`

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to be able to measure force without touching the screen. For instance, to use as a scale.